# try to solve the following partial differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

let we have $$y=y(x,t)$$
we want to solve the following partial differential equation
$$\frac{c^2}{x}\left(1-\left(\frac{x}{c}\right)^2\right)y_x-ty_t=0$$ where $c>0$ is a constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a very easy equation and it is unclear what are you asking. If you need a general solution, use the characteristics
$$\frac{dx}{ds}=\frac{c^{2}}{x}\Big(1-\Big(\frac{x}{c}\Big)^{2}\Big)$$
$$\frac{dt}{ds}=-t$$
This gives the general solution
$$y(x, t)=f\Big(\frac{t}{\sqrt{c^{2}-x^{2}}}\Big)$$
If you've needed just any function solving the equation, then this equation is separable, and it is easy to show that for two arbitrary constants $a, C$ the function:
$$y(x, t)=C\Big(\frac{t}{\sqrt{c^{2}-x^{2}}}\Big)^{a}$$
solves the equation.